# Dell Precision 5530 suspend problem and other problems w/ 18.10

Tags: nvidia, dell, 18.10

I just bought a Dell Precision 5530 with a Xeon(R) E-2176M, Quadro P2000, 16GB, 4K Touchscreen and 256gb SSD.

It came with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, but it wasn't really stable so I installed Ubuntu 18.10. No problems with installation but here are the problems I have using it :

- Sometimes cursor and system freeze and I'm forced to shutdown the computer using the power button
- Fans are running in a mysterious way, sometimes they just start and run @ 2500rpm and stop 10s later over and over again, while the CPU temp is about 45-50°C.
- When the system goes to sleep after inactivity or after closing the laptop, it's impossible to wake it up, I'm forced to hard reboot.

What I've tried :

- Updating bios to 1.6.0
- Installing NVIDIA 415 driver (and using NVIDIA driver instead of xorg-video-nouveau)
- Editing my /etc/default/grub file to :

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"`
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux-Dell-Video"`

Do you have any idea what I could do ? Maybe I should try 18.04 but I'm not quiet sure if it's going to be any better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact same specs as your model. However I've got mine finally working with the following setup.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- No changes to grub
- Installed all the `linux-generic-hwe` packages
- installed the nvidia-390 driver

After this everything (suspend ect.) seems to be working in Gnome Wayland and ARMA 3 gives me decent frame rates. I've only tried it today and therefore haven't really invested much time into Gnome Xorg or i3wm. However it seems to crash everytime I select one of those environments.

Comment: I would like to install 18.04 LTS on my Dell Precision 5530 with following specs:
Intel Core i9-8950HK, 32GB RAM, Quadro P2000, 4 Screen, Intel Wifi Link 9260 2x2.
Coming from Kubuntu 18.04 and had minor graphic issues. Always needed to restart the system when connecting a screen. Do you might have any tips before I start the installation. SWAP partition or SWAP file (had this on Kubuntu)? Which driver to use for my NVidia card and how to install? Should I let the system install all drivers during installation our should I better do it myself afterwards?

Comment: I'm currently not using the Nvidia GPU to save battery and I'm running on Arch. However you might want to use 19.10 and then upgrade to 20.04 at the beginning of April then you're on the newest LTS.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. However, I installed 18.04 LTS without a internet connection and installed all drivers later when the system was set up. The GPU is still without a driver and turned off, will look into this problem when 20.04 LTS is out. But I guess I will take the 390 or 430 driver.